# Javascript flashing for a second but not printing in textbox

Tags: javascript

Amount

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
         function interestVal() 
            {
                var x = document.Amounts.valOfCar.value;
                var y = document.Amounts.interestofCar.value;
                var z = x+y;
                document.Amounts.carInterest.value=z;
            }
        -->
    </script>


</head>
<body background="bg.jpg">
        <p>Calculate the cost of your car</p> 
        <form name = Amounts> 
            <p>Value of a car <input type="text"  value="" name=valOfCar></p>
            <p>Interest @15% <input type="text" value="" name=interestofCar></p>
            <p>Value + Interest<input type="text" name=carInterest></p>
            <p><input type=submit value=Calculate onClick=interestVal()></p>
        </form>
</body>
```

Comment: A lot more information is required before this can even be answered.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive about your problem? What does 'flashing' mean?

Comment: If you don't put some effort in your question, no one will be willing to help you.

Comment: `<form name = Amounts> ` Is this valid HTML or XHTML?

Comment: First things first...what kind of a Doctype are you using for this interesting version of HTML?

Comment: flashing means it is displaying the right answer in the textboxes but for only a split second. it then makes them empty again

Comment: People can be a little harsh with newcomers here, charles. Please don't let that discourage you. We really are here to help.

Comment: thank DOK for the answer. I am a junior Java programmer so was wondering why it was not working. thanks for the button info. it really makes sense. how can i contact you regularly with other question if you are able to help me with java. I have developed a game in java so now creating the same thing as an online app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. I was able to reproduce your problem by just copying your code and running it. This code will run. The principal change I made, which I believe was the source of the problem, was altering from an **input of type submit to a button**. As a submit, it was doing a postback, which caused the contents of the controls to disappear. Using a button avoids the postback.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
     function interestVal() {
         var x = document.Amounts.valOfCar.value;
         var y = document.Amounts.interestofCar.value;
         var z = x * y;
         document.Amounts.carInterest.value = z;
     }
        -->
    </script>


</head>
<body background="bg.jpg">
        <p>Calculate the cost of your car</p> 
        <form name = "Amounts"> 
            <p>Value of a car <input type="text"   name="valOfCar" /></p>
            <p>Interest @15% <input type="text"  name="interestofCar" /></p>
            <p>Value + Interest<input type="text" name="carInterest" /></p>
            <p><button type="button" onclick="interestVal();" >Calculate</button></p>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Another potential problem is that by summing `x` and `y`, you get their concatenated result, which is probably not what you want. I have changed that to multiplying `x` times `y`.

Finally, I have enclosed many of the attribute values in quotes and made the inputs self-closing by ending the with `/>` instead of `>`.